# Gigya implementation , retype password dialog issue

Tags: android, gigya

I have implemented Gigya in my app, wherein I am logging into gmail,facebook,twitter using Gigya login Apis. The issue is that whenever I am logging in through gmail(which is the primary account on the device), the system's retype password dialog keeps appearing always after few minutes. This is odd because I am not logging out from gmail on device[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am one of the engineers at Gigya and I hope I can help you out here.

I'll start by pointing out that, on Android, Gigya would not ever trigger the system password dialog like that. The method that Gigya uses to log a user does not cross over into the system level account log in.

I would say to check the password you are plugging in to begin with. The Google Chrome notification icon along with the three other warning icons indicates to me that either Chrome or the system is trying to log you in and failing with that password.

From personal experience I can tell you that for the same Google account, I have one password that will log into Google services and another password that is used for syncing data from and to that same account. At some point they were the same password, but after resetting to a new password, the log in password was reset but the sync password remained the same as before.

I hope that sheds some light on why you are seeing this dialog every so often.

Best,
CodeMonkeyG